# MinMax - generating game tree

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe, minmax

I try to write a MinMax program in Java for connect-four game, but this program should also be applicable to other games. But, I encountered a problem, which I cannot pass for few days. The values for nodes are not set properly. I am sharing my piece of code which is responsible for generating a tree.

Maybe you will notice where I made a mistake.

If anyone could help me with this, I will be very happy.

```
public Node generateTree(Board board, int depth) {
    Node rootNode = new Node(board);
    generateSubtree(rootNode, depth);
    minMax(rootNode, depth);
    return rootNode;
}

private void generateSubtree(Node subRootNode, int depth) {
    Board board = subRootNode.getBoard();

    if (depth == 0) {
        subRootNode.setValue(board.evaluateBoard());
        return;
    }

    for (Move move : board.generateMoves()) {
        Board tempBoard = board.makeMove(move);
        Node tempNode = new Node(tempBoard);
        subRootNode.addChild(tempNode);
        generateSubtree(tempNode, depth - 1);
    }
}

public void minMax(Node rootNode, int depth) {
    maxMove(rootNode, depth);
}

public int maxMove(Node node, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        return node.getValue();
    }
    int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Node childNode : node.getChildren()) {
        int tempValue = minMove(childNode, depth - 1);
        childNode.setValue(tempValue);
        if (tempValue > bestValue) {
            bestValue = tempValue;
        }
    }
    return bestValue;
}

public int minMove(Node node, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        return node.getValue();
    }
    int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Node childNode : node.getChildren()) {
        int tempValue = maxMove(childNode, depth - 1);
        childNode.setValue(tempValue);
        if (tempValue < bestValue) {
            bestValue = tempValue;
        }
    }
    return bestValue;
}
```

**Board** class is the representation of the board state.

**Move** class hold the move to perform (integer [0-8] for tic-tac-toe, [0-6] for Connect Four).

**Node** class holds the Move and value how good given move is. Also, holds all its children.

In the code I use this method like this:

```
Node newNode = minmax.generateTree(board, depth, board.getPlayer());
Move newMove = new TicTacToeMove(board.getPlayer(), newNode.getBestMove().getMove(), depth);
board = board.makeMove(newMove);
```

And when it's obvious that given move is a losing move (or winning), I do not receive this move.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include an example of what you input, what you think the result should be and what it is instead.

Comment: Hi,
**Board** class is representation of the board state.
**Move** class hold the move to perform (integer [0-8] for tictactoe, [0-6] for Connect four).
**Node** class holds the Move and value how good given move is. Also holds all its children.

In the code I use this method like this:
`Node newNode = minmax.generateTree(board, depth, board.getPlayer());
Move newMove = new TicTacToeMove(board.getPlayer(), newNode.getBestMove().getMove(), depth);
board = board.makeMove(newMove);`

And when its obvious that given move is a losing move (or winning), I do not receive this move.

Comment: What does "I do not receive this move." mean? Is it a network game and a winning or losing move isn't being send to you? Do you mean it's not put on the board? Does your tree not gain a new entry?

Comment: Hi. output of method generateTree(...) should be the root of given state of board. Then when i do node.getBestMove() - it should return Move with best value (after minmax algorithm). Then move.getMove() returns integer for given move - where pawn should be placed. I guess something in minmax() method is wrong, because generateTree() method reaches the bottom on the game and finds losing/winning move.

Comment: Look, I want to help you, but... you STILL haven't told me what actually goes wrong. *it should return Move with best value* <- Does that mean it doesn't? What does it return instead?  *generateTree() method reaches the bottom on the game* <- How do you know that? Or is that still part of your guess? I mean... I simply want to know what the problem is. You say something is wrong but you don't say what. Why are you here? Did you get a bluescreen? Did your pc explode? Was there a 5 returned by your `move.getMove()` method when you wanted a 4?

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if you took a moment to look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because if you followed that I could just reproduce the problem and SEE what's wrong, but since I can't, please try to explain it better :D

Comment: Does `Node` constructor perform a deep copy of the board?

Comment: Hi, sorry that I'm not clear with responses. Maybe the screenshould will help [http://imgur.com/a/xKuR1].
As we can see, the generateTree returned Node with Move 1 - and it corresponds to top middle slot. However, we can clearly see that middle left slot should be returned (to prevent losing). Yet however, two moves earlier it calculated properly where to place to prevent losing [http://imgur.com/a/xKuR1]

Comment: @ReutSharabani No. It only assigns this.board = board;. However in board.makeMove(move) I copy board state to newBoard object, perform the move and then return newBoard

Comment: I copied wrong URL twice. Url to unexpected behaviour: http://imgur.com/a/vP8Fu Url to proper behaviour: http://imgur.com/a/xKuR1

Comment: I can also provide the whole code under this link: https://github.com/Xing92/MinmaxCfTTT/tree/master/Combined_MinMax/src

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you did make a couple of mistakes. About 3-4, depending on how you count ;) Took me a bit of debugging to figure it all out, but I finally got an answer for you :D

**Mistake #1: All your parents always get twins (that poor mother)**

This is only the case with the code you uploaded, not the code in your question, so maybe we count it as half a mistake?
Since your trees aren't that big yet and it won't destroy your algorithm, this was the least important one anyway. Still, it's something to watch out for.
In your uploaded code, you do this in your `generateSubtree` method:

```
Node tempNode = new Node(tempBoard, move, subRootNode);
subRootNode.addChild(tempNode);
```

As that constructor already adds the child to the subRootNode, the second line always adds it a second time.

**Mistake #2: That darn depth**

If you haven't reached your desired depth yet, but the game is already decided, you completely ignore that. So in your provided example that won't work, if - for example - you look at making move 7 instead of 3 (which would be the 'right' move) and then the opponent does move 3, you don't count it as -10 points because you haven't reached your depth yet. It still won't get any children, so even in your minmax, it will never realize it's a screwed up way to go.

Which is why every move is 'possible' in this scenario and you just get the first one returned.

In the previous moves, there was luckily always a way to reach a losing move with your opponents third move (aka move #5), which is why those were called correctly.

Alright, so how do we fix it?

```
private void generateSubtree(Node subRootNode, int depth, int player) {
    Board board = subRootNode.getBoard();
    List<Move> moveList = board.generateMoves();

    if (depth == 0 || moveList.isEmpty()) {
        subRootNode.setValue(board.evaluateBoard(player));
        return;
    }

    for (Move move : moveList) {
        Board tempBoard = board.makeMove(move);
        Node tempNode = new Node(tempBoard, move, subRootNode);
        generateSubtree(tempNode, depth - 1, player);
    }
}
```

Just get the move list beforehand and then look if it's empty (your `generateMoves()` method of the `Board` class (thank god you provided that by the way ;)) already checks if the game is over, so if it is, there won't be any moves generated. Perfect time to check the score).

**Mistake #3: That darn depth again**

Didn't we just go over this?

Sadly, your Min Max algorithm itself has the same problem. It will only even look at your values if you have reached the desired depth. You need to change that.

However, this is a bit more complicated, since you don't have a nice little method that already checks if the game is finished for you.

You could check to see if your value was set, but here's the problem: It might be set to `0` and you need to take that into account as well (so you can't just do `if (node.getValue() != 0)`).

I just set the initial value of each node to `-1` instead and did a check against `-1`. It's not... you know... pretty. But it works.

```
public class Node {
    private Board board;
    private Move move;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();;
    private boolean isRootNode = false;

    private int value = -1;
   ...
```

And this in the `maxMove`:

```
public int maxMove(Node node, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0 || node.getValue() != -1) {
        return node.getValue();
    }
    int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Node childNode : node.getChildren()) {
        int tempValue = minMove(childNode, depth - 1);
        childNode.setValue(tempValue);
        if (tempValue > bestValue) {
            bestValue = tempValue;
        }
    }               
    return bestValue;
}
```

It works the same for `minMove` of course.

**Mistake #4: The player is screwing with you**

Once I changed all that, it took me a moment with the debugger to realize why it still wouldn't work.

This last mistake was not in the code you provided in the question btw. Shame on you! ;)

Turns out it was this wonderful piece of code in your `TicTacToeBoard` class:

```
@Override
public int getPlayer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

And since you called

```
        MinMax minmax = new MinMax();
        Node newNode = minmax.generateTree(board, (Integer) spinner.getValue(), board.getPlayer());
```

in your `makeMove` method of `TicTacToeMainWindow`, you would always start out with the wrong player.

As you can probably guess yourself, you just need to change it to:

```
public int getPlayer() {
    return this.player;
}
```

And it should do the trick.

**Also:**

Just a couple of things I'd like to remark at this point:

- Clean up your imports! Your TicTacToe actually still imports your ConnectFour classes! And for no reason.
- Your board is rotated and mirrored in your board array. WHY? You know how annoying that is to debug? I mean, I guess you probably do :D Also, if you're having problems with your code and you need to debug it's extremely helpful to overwrite your boards `toString()` method, because that will give you a very nice and easy way to look at your board in the debugger. You can even use it to rotate it again, so you see don't have to look at it lying on the side ;)
- While we're at the subject of the board... this is just me but... I always tried clicking on the painted surface first and then had to remember: Oh yeah, there were buttons :D I mean... why not just put the images on the buttons or implement a `MouseListener` so you can actually just click on the painted surface?
- When providing code and/or example images, please take out your test outputs. I'm talking about the `Player 1 won!`s of course ;)
- Please learn what a complete, verifiable and minimal example is for the next time you ask a question on StackOverflow. The one in your question wasn't complete or verifiable and the one you provided on github was... well... not complete (the images were missing), but complete enough. It was also verifiable, but it was NOT minimal. You will get answers a LOT sooner if you follow the guidelines.